# Bootstrap-vue open modal from modal

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

Is there a way to open a new modal from another modal in bootstrap-vue?

```
<div>
  <b-btn v-b-modal.modal1>Launch demo modal</b-btn>
  <b-modal id="modal1" title="Bootstrap-Vue">
    <b-btn v-b-modal.modal2>Launch another modal</b-btn>
    <b-modal id="modal2" title="Bootstrap-Vue">
      Vueception
    </b-modal>
  </b-modal>
</div>
```

When I run this example on https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/play it will open the first modal but when I click the button to open the 2nd modal it will cause the first one to close.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to reorder your components so that the button is inside the first modal but the second modal should be outside so that it doesn't get closed with the first modal ..

```
<div>
  <b-btn v-b-modal.modal1>Launch demo modal</b-btn>
  <b-modal id="modal1" title="Bootstrap-Vue">
    <b-btn v-b-modal.modal2>Launch another modal</b-btn>
  </b-modal>
  <b-modal id="modal2" title="Bootstrap-Vue">
    Vueception
  </b-modal>
</div>
```

check this [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/xjwwyxwr9w)

Comment: @boussadjrabrahim Yeah we must have been trying to solve it at the same time. Initially I thought about using [PortalVue](https://linusborg.github.io/portal-vue/#/) but it seems the solution is much simpler. Thanks for the +1 :)

Comment: It works but it still closes the parent modal. I guess I need something more like the way Nested Modals work in [reactstrap](https://reactstrap.github.io/components/modals/).

Comment: Upgrade to the latest version of BootstrapVue, which has added in multiple modal support.  Official Bootstrap v4.x does not support multiple open modals, but BootstrapVue has added in custom support for it.  Also do not place a `b-modal` inside of another `b-modal`.  It will cause issues.

Comment: I'm doing exactly this, except that modal1 has a directive to launch modal2 and modal2 has a directive to launch model1. Both b-modals have the no-stacking option, so the effect that I am trying to achieve is a toggle between the two. What happens: modal1 can go to modal2, and modal2 to modal1, but once on the second step for either case, the directive no longer does anything to change modals more than once. So you can only toggle once. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Update to my comment above: The issue is with directives. It works as expected if, instead of using directives, a click event is defined to open the other modal, eg @click="$root.$emit('bv::show::modal', id + '_subscribe', $event.target)"